# Jenkins GitHub Clone Permission Denied

Tags: github, jenkins, git-clone, jenkins-plugins

When running the job to clone my devel branch of my repo in Jenkins, I get the following error:

```
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm running Jenkins on CentOS 6 and have the GitHub Hooks set up correctly. How do I correct this? Do I need a deploy key even though I have the GitHub plugin installed with a valid user with access to the private organization repo?

I have a github account for my jenkins server, with a dsa key that resides in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh that has been added to the github account, and this error is still occuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "I have the GitHub plugin installed with a valid user with access to the private organization repo" and I am no familiar with Jenkins but you definitely need a deployment key added to that repo for authenticating your requests. I think you have just specified the git global author name etc.

Comment: I have a github account for my jenkins server (which the GitHub plugin is configured to used and verified that the login is correct), with a dsa key that resides in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh that has been added to the github account, and this error is still occuring

Comment: Update: I just needed to add the github server to known_hosts. all is working now for those having the same problem!